# How to cut off a portion of a html inside <div> and store it as html string by using xpath and domdocument?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I would like to cut off some portion of html, I can take it by using XPath and DomDocument but the problem is that I need result as a html code string. Normally I would use reg. expr. for that but I wouldn't like to do a complicated search pattern that would mach the begining and the end of  tag.

That's the example input:

```
some html code before
<div>this <b>is</b> what I want</div>
some html after
```

and the output:

```
<div>this <b>is</b> what I want</div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
 subject = 'some html code before
<div>this <b>is</b> what I want</div>
some html after';

$doc = new DOMDocument();                   
$doc->loadHTML($subject);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//div/*");
echo $result->saveHTML();
```

but i got only error:
    Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::saveHTML()

Does anyone know how to get the result as a html string by using DomDocument and XPath?

Comment: +1 for trying on your own first and having some code to backup your question. And **welcome to SO**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$subject = 'some html code before
<div>this <b>is</b> what I want</div>
some html after';

$doc = new DOMDocument();                   
$doc->loadHTML($subject);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//div");
echo $doc->saveHTML($result->item(0)); //echoes what you want :)
```

The `saveHTML` function belongs to the `DOMDocument` object, you can't call it directly on the node (much less on the NodeList, which is what the query returns), but what you *can* do is pass it the node as a param.

Also, your query was wrong: what you want is the `div` element (i.e. `//div`), not its children (`//div/*`).

Comment: echo $doc->saveHTML($result->item(0)); //echoes what you want :)
Unlucky this creates:

Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in...

and there is no html string output at all

Comment: I know what's going on: that parameter was added in php 5.3.6 (it says [here in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)). Is it possible for you to upgrade your php?

Comment: You've got the point, true I don't have the latest version for sure. I'm not able to upgrade it as it is remote hosting but I will ask my provider for that.

It is good to know that there are at least two solutions of the topic, the one that I presented (for older php versions), and the other - more concise that you presented for the latest ver.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Gentleman for pointing out my missunderstanding with accessing methods that are not aviailable in a child object. But line:

```
echo $doc->saveHTML($result->item(0));
```

generates only warning (without the html sting I want to have). Luckily I found another soulution and here it is:

```
<?php
$subject = '<html>
    <head>
        <title>A very short ebook</title>
        <meta name="charset" value="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="bookTitle">A very short ebook</h1>
        <p style="text-align:right">Written by Kovid Goyal</p>
        <div class="introduction">
            <p>A very short ebook to demonstrate the use of XPath.</p>
        </div>

        <h2 class="chapter">Chapter One</h2>
        <p>This is a truly fascinating chapter.</p>

        <h2 class="chapter">Chapter Two</h2>
        <p>A worthy continuation of a fine tradition.</p>
    </body>
</html>';


$doc = new DOMDocument();                   
$doc->loadHTML($subject);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//div");

//echo $doc->saveHTML($result->item(0));

echo domNodeList_to_string($result);

function domNodeList_to_string($DomNodeList) {
    $output = '';
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    while ( $node = $DomNodeList->item($i) ) {
        // import node
        $domNode = $doc->importNode($node, true);
        // append node
        $doc->appendChild($domNode);
        $i++;
    }
    $output = $doc->saveHTML();
    $output = print_r($output, 1);
    // I added this because xml output and ajax do not like each others
    //$output = htmlspecialchars($output);
    return $output;
}
php>
```

so if one has a query like that:

```
$result = $xpath->query("//div");
```

then will get the raw html string output:

```
<div class="introduction">
        <p>A very short ebook to demonstrate the use of XPath.</p>
    </div>
```

if the query is:

```
$result = $xpath->query("//p");
```

then output will be:

```
<p style="text-align:right">Written by Kovid Goyal</p><p>A very short ebook to demonstrate the use of XPath.</p><p>This is a truly fascinating chapter.</p><p>A worthy continuation of a fine tradition.</p>
```

Does anyone know simpler (embeded in php) method to get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

As per the php manual docs on [`DOMXPath::query`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php), the function:

> Returns a DOMNodeList containing all nodes matching the given XPath
>   expression. Any expression which does not return nodes will return an
>   empty DOMNodeList.

This means that the `$result` in the following code will be a [`DOMNodeList`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object. So if you want to get individual HTML code out from inside it you'll need to use methods available with a `DOMNodeList` object. In this case, the `item` method:

```
$result = $xpath->query("//div");
echo $doc->saveHTML($result->item(0));
```

`$result->item(0)` returns the first `DOMNode` in the `DOMNodeList` created by your xpath query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$subject = 'some html code before<div>this <b>is</b> what I want</div>some html after';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');                   
$doc->loadHTML($subject);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//div");
$docSave = new DOMDocument('1.0');
foreach ( $result as $node ) {
    $domNode = $docSave->importNode($node, true);
    $docSave->appendChild($domNode);
}
echo $docSave->saveHTML();
```

Comment: It works!, That's even better that I proposed, shorter and simpler :)